# Comparação timestamp e CurrentDate

Tags: ionic

Ora viva pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um ionic app e preciso comparar duas datas no ngfor, porém acontece que a comparação só considera o dia...
Por exemplo: comparando 02/08/2022 e 07/02/2022 retorna 07/02/2022 como maior.
Como faço para tomar em consideração o mês e o ano também?

```
<li *ngFor="let item of cliente">
<div *ngif='(item.datanascimento | date:"shortDate") < (dataActual)' style...
```

A datanascimento é um timestamp do firebase que é convertida em shortDate e a dataActual é uma variável proveniente do tolocaledatestring do js.

Comment: Importante em vez de duplicar postagens, [editar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/561242/70) e detalhar melhor a dúvida. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o campo de comentários aqui está desativado, mas funciona na postagem original.